# Get Model Data Fields In Same Model

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I Have Model nane is Usertest and it has some fields Like

```
id , name , age , birthdate ...ect
```

i have call function afterSave in model . I can get the Saved id by use `$this->id;`

can i get other fields like age or birthdate inside function afterSave?

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class UserTest extends AppModel
{
    public $useDbConfig = 'default';
    public function afterSave($created, $options = array())
    {
        parent::afterSave($created, $options);
        $NewID = $this->id;
        $NewAge = ????
    }
}
```

Comment: without having access to your code which inserts the data into the database, I can't help you.

Comment: What I can suggest you to do is to once the data is saved in the database, before returning the id, use the id to query the database and get the row as a object and return the row object.

Comment: How Can i do it inside model ??

Comment: What framework are you using

Comment: CakePHP Version 2.x

Comment: i well Edit The Post

Comment: You Can Look To Code